# Date returned as Day of week Number 1-7

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having difficulty with the Day of week number function in SQL. The excel equivalent i use frequently is...

```
=WEEKDAY("datevalue",1)
```

This of course will return Sunday = 1, Monday = 2 etc... What is the Access Sql equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will suffice to get the answer needed.

```
weekday(date)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `DatePart`:

```
DatePart ("w", date)
```

[Reference](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php)

Answer (score 1):

This would help

```
DATEPART(dd, date)
```

[Returns int](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp)

Comment: In Access, "dd" as the interval argument throws run-time error #5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: HansUp.  Good point.  I am well acquainted with Excels Help, I will make sure to do this in the future.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

It is datepart()

> For Example
>
> DatePart ("yyyy", #15/10/1998#) would return 1998
>
> DatePart ("m", #15/10/2003#)   would return 10
>
> DatePart ("d", #15/10/2003#)   would return 15